# How to annotate foreignkey

Tags: python, django

```py
class Bookmark(CoreModel):

    """Bookmark Model Definition"""

    spot = models.ForeignKey(
        "spots.Spot", related_name="bookmarks", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class Spot(models.Model):

    """Spot Model Definition"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    coords = models.PointField(srid=4326)
```

this is my model

```py
    ref_location = Point(query.longitude, query.latitude, srid=4326)
    bookmarks = Bookmark.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).annotate(
        distance=Distance("spot__coords", ref_location)
    )
    for bookmark in bookmarks:
        print(bookmark.spot.distance) <- error
```

this is my queryset

`bookmark.distance` is working, but i want `bookmark.spot.distance`

"distance" appears in "bookmark". How can I annotate "distance" in "spot"?

Comment: See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33242). The idea to add such ability was proposed and rejected (wontfix). Why is it important for you to annotate related field instead of main object?

Comment: @SUTerliakov
Thank you.
I want to keep the existing Spot Object form in Bookmark.
Inevitably, I will implement it in the main object.